# Use variable in list expect script

Tags: expect

In expect script, I have snippet code like

```
set log_path "/var/log/"  
set opt_path "/opt/"  

set path_list {$log_path $opt_path}  
list $path_list  

puts $path_list  # ==> $log_path $opt_path
```

It always prints `$log_path $opt_path`

How can I make it prints `/var/log /opt/`?

Answer (score 0):

In `Tcl`, variable substitution will not happen inside braces (though there are some exceptions). Please refer [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M12). You should use double quotes so that the variable interpolation can happen.

```
set path_list "$log_path $opt_path"
puts $path_list
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want path_list to be created/treated as a list, you may use list instead of {} to initialize:

Code:

```
set log_path "/var/log/"
set opt_path "/opt/"

set path_list [list $log_path $opt_path]
puts $path_list
```

Execution output:

```
/var/log/ /opt/
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this one and it works

set path_list [list $log_path $opt_path]

Thank you so much.

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and accept the answer.